# Centering a variable width column of text in a UIScrollView using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a seemingly simple design that I can't express using Auto Layout constraints: in a UIScrollView, I need to show a centered column of text that has a minimum width of 300 pts and a maximum width of 500 pts (maintaining a margin of at least 10 pts in all cases.)

The column of text is actually a UIStackView, but that doesn't really matter for this discussion, the view could just as easily be a UIImageView with aspect fit.

I've tried using padding views with different content hugging and compression resistance, a stack view with a horizontal axis, width constraints with less-than-or-equal constants, etc. I want to do it all within the storyboard, sniffing around during layout changes or using size classes feels like cheating.

(Some of my experiments have caused Xcode to hang while updating the storyboard: giving me a painful hint that there's no solution for these kinds of constraints.)

And before you suggest it, [I have read about the subtleties of UIScrollView and Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

This seems like an unsolvable problem, which is a shame. It's a very common pattern and something designers love to use with CSS (using min-width and max-width). I hope that I'm missing something here and that someone with a deeper knowledge of auto layout can explain a way to do this (and act as a reference for others who would like to do the same thing.)

**Update:** The suggestions by Adam and Ben below are very helpful for achieving this layout. But as soon as you get multiple blocks of text the auto layout iterative solver can't handle it (and Xcode hangs.) For more information: http://openradar.appspot.com/25173433

Comment: Erica Sadun has a UIScrollView subclass in her AutoLayout book that might help. She might have the knowledge of AutoLayout that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is actually pretty straightforward! I've included a [storyboard file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3c0s43jykgsb0r/SO_Solution-20160313.storyboard?dl=0) as a demo. The key bits for the text inside of the content view:

- Leading/Trailing Margins >= 10
- Width >= 300
- Width <= 500
- Center Align

No priority changes are required, unless you have other content that is going to take precedence.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sample, Ben. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem, but it did help me write a Radar that shows Xcode is broken as soon as the layout gets more complex. http://openradar.appspot.com/25173433

Comment: Glad it got you further! I checked out the storyboard in the radar. I've seen this behavior before, and you can blame the stack views being in relation to each other. Eliminate the equal width constraints by assigning the same setup (<=10 margins, 300<=width<=500). My impression is there's something incorrect in the order of operations when dealing with multiple, related stack views that leads to an infinite loop of updates.

Comment: The problem with eliminating the equal width constraints for the stack views is that the caring label width causes the stack width to vary: the resulting ragged edge looks bad. In theory, it should be possible to move the labels out of the stack view and give them explicit constraints (instead of relying on the automatic ones.) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Not sure if this helps (hence being in a comment) but having just those 4 constraints is still ambiguous. The width can be anywhere between 300 and 500 and there's nothing there to help the system determine it. What if you add the following constraint: Width = 500, priority 999? That way the text view will be 500 wide as long as it can.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following the problem correctly, I think I've got a fairly simple setup that works for this.

I start with the scrollview, then add to it a basic UIView to act as a container. I pin the UIView to the scrollview's top, bottom, leading, and trailing edges so that the scrollview's content size is managed properly. I add a constraint to that container view to match widths with the scrollview.

I then add the UIStackView to the container view, and give it these constraints:

- Align Center X to Superview
- Trailing Space to Superview >= 10
- Leading Space to Superview >= 10
- Width = 500 with Priority 750
- Width >= 300
- Bottom Space to Superview = 10
- Top Space to Superview = 10

All with the default priorities except width = 500. Then I put some labels in the stack view, and the result I get is a column that will have at least a 10 point margin on either side but will never be wider than 500 points, and will go down to 300 points wide depending on the content of the stack view.

Answer (score 0):

Try a leading and trailing constraint of 10 but set their priority to 750. Then a center horizontally and a >= 300 width and <= 500 width and leave those at 1000 priority.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution, if I understand the problem correctly. I tested this with a UILabel inside the UIScrollView, but it should work for any view with an intrinsic size. For whatever inner view you’re using, give these constraints a try:

- Width <= 500
- Width >= 300
- Align center X to Superview
- Top space to Superview = 10
- Bottom space to Superview = 10
- Leading space to Superview = 10 (priority 750)
- Trailing space to Superview = 10 (priority 750)
- Horizontal content compression resistance priority: 250

Setting a low priority for the horizontal content compression resistance is key. My UILabel has a bunch of text in it so its intrinsic content size is something like 2200px. With the default horizontal compression resistance, it will always expand to the 500px max width and the scrollview will scroll both horizontally and vertically on smaller screens. I only want vertical scrolling so I set a lower horizontal compression resistance priority on the UILabel, which tells auto layout to squeeze it to fit.